# STRAPI is cutting the last 3 chars

Tags: strapi

I'm using the strapi 3.0.0-beta.15
DB - mongo 4.2.2

After updating one of model fields - which is type of 'text', it is cutting the last three chars and set it to '000'. Saw this only if there are numbers at field.

**Writting text (before saving**

[image]

**After saving**

[image]

Did anyone have stacked with such problems yet?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in the last version of Strapi (at least beta.18)

I suggest you update your application using a migration guide if necessary, or, using the application update guide that is into the documentation.

Here is what I did in a short video - https://www.loom.com/share/23076126176546708f9dcaa7eac1924c

Comment: Great! Thanks! I supposed that at the textField there was a parseInt operator that is cutting bugInt.